# symfony many to many

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I'm looking at creating the following scenario.

1. I have many templates
2. I have many users (sfGuardUser)
3. I want it so when I edit a template, I can assign many users to a particular.

Am I correct in thinking I'll need 3 tables in my schema?

```
Template
User
TemplateUser
```

and define the relations within these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Examples: [#1](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/03?orm=Doctrine#chapter_03_the_schema) [#2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html#many-to-many)